In pycharm, what is the test_xxx.http file, for a fastapi project?
After creating a fastapi project, via pycharm, I got such a file:
test_main.http:
# Test your FastAPI endpoints
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Accept: application/json

###

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/User
Accept: application/json

and can run it in pycharm by click the run button appear in the file.
But, what is this test_xxx.http file ?
I've checked fastapi doc: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/
Also searched on google, didn't found anything mention such .http file.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/fastapi-project.html#endpoints and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/endpoints-tool-window.html - it's PyCharm specific functionality for testing endpoints.

The .http file you found in your FastAPI project, like test_main.http, is a feature specific to some IDEs like PyCharm (and other JetBrains products). It allows you to write HTTP requests directly within the file and run them from the IDE. This functionality is not exclusive to FastAPI but can be used for testing any HTTP-based APIs or endpoints.
Purpose of .http File
In PyCharm, .http files serve as a simple way to test your API endpoints without needing to write Python code or use external tools like Postman or curl. You can write HTTP requests in this file, and the IDE provides a built-in runner to execute these requests and view the responses within the editor.
